# GET verb not calling the correct action

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I scraped this controller code directly out of the MS .NET tutorials and it works fine:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    Product[] products = new Product[]
    {
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
    };

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("id = " + id);
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }
}
```

In the same namespace I have created 2 of my own controllers and both display the same problem - only the first action (GetAll*()) responds to a GET, the second action (GetVehicle()) does not and when set by itself and decorated with [HttpGet] errors out with:

```
{
    "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
}
```

This controller seems identical to the product controller above:

```
public class VehiclesController : ApiController
{
    Vehicle[] vehicles = new Vehicle[]
    {
        new Vehicle { Code = 1, Type = "type1", BumperID = "H0002" },
        new Vehicle { Code = 2, Type = "type2", BumperID = "T0016" }
    };

    public IEnumerable<Vehicle> GetAllVehicles()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetAllVehicles()");
        return vehicles;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetVehicle(int code)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetVehicle() code = " + code);
        var vehicle = vehicles.FirstOrDefault((v) => v.Code == code);
        if (vehicle == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(vehicle);
    }
}
```

but only the first action gets called. What am I missing? Same exact issue with a separate SecurityController. Pretty new to .NET.....

Self-hosting route maps added:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

With the above code,

`http://localhost:8080/api/vehicles`

works, but

`http://localhost:8080/api/vehicles/1`

does not.

Anyone getting here via search Jeffrey Rennie's answer below is correct - the `id` in `{id}` is literal.

Comment: Can you please give us your route maps

Comment: Edited my post and added the mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming `GetVehicle()`'s argument from `code` to `id`.  It's related to Anthony Liriano's answer.  The default routing pattern expects a argument named `id`.

Comment: Kaboom - I didn't realize the `id` in `{id}` in the Configuration was literal. Thanks - will mark as the answer as soon as it allows me to do so. Very new to .NET...

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the Route and Verb Attribute. This requires that you're using the System.Web.Http library. You can find more information on [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/your/route/here")]
public IHttpActionResult GetVehicle(int code)
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetVehicle() code = " + code);
    var vehicle = vehicles.FirstOrDefault((v) => v.Code == code);
    if (vehicle == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(vehicle);
}
```

Comment: I tried that - it had no effect, and isn't used that way in the simple tutorial though I will be going that route later in the port. @Jeffrey Rennie is correct below and solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Or decorate your api endpoint as such like

```
   [HttpGet("{code}/GetVehicleById")]
   public IHttpActionResult GetVehicle(int code)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetVehicle() code = " + code);
        var vehicle = vehicles.FirstOrDefault((v) => v.Code == code);
        if (vehicle == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(vehicle);
    }
```

Your api endpoint call would be then

```
api/vehicles/123/GetVehicleById
```